# Difference between blocking and split plot-design?

Tags: experiment-design, blocking, split-plot

What is the difference between blocking in an experiment design and a split plot design?

Comment: Hello. Ben. Did you check the definitions? Why do you feel you fail to discern them?

Comment: Blocking is used to construct single blocks within the experiment to consider factors which can not or hardly be changed. A split plot design targets the situation when there are hard and easy to change factors. To me, it looks quite similar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What is needed to understand is what split plot design does and how it is different from blocking.

Consider a factor $A$ with $p$ levels. If an RBD is constructed with, say, $r$ blocks, $p$ levels of $A$ are allocated at random at each of the $r$ plots.

Nothing intricate.

Let there be another factor of interest $B$ with $q$ levels. How to compare with the levels of $A?$ If the former needs only a smaller amount of material as that of the latter, then one ingenious way to implement the same is to divide each whole plot into $q$ sub-plots, where $q$ levels of $B$ are allocated at random. This layout is the basis of the split plot design.

$\rm [I]$ compares SPD and RBD, the foremost of which is:

$\bullet$ Albeit there is no **net** gain in precision in both designs, there is an **increased** precision on the main effect of the sub-plot treatment $B$ and the interaction effect of $AB$ (at the cost of precision on the main effect $A$).

---

### Reference:

$\rm [I]$ Experimental Designs, *William G. Cochran, Gertrude M. Cox,* Asia Publishing House, $1959,$ sec. $7.13,$ pp. $296-297.$

Comment: Thank you, just to make it clear (for me): Split plot is actually quite different from blocking, I related them only because I stumbled over single sentences which made them sound similar..

Comment: @Ben they are related but they were developed for different purposes.